# How can i use a lib like loglevel to do logging in my react/redux web app

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I am using [davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) and trying to figure out how to use some third party logging library which I can conditionally set the visible log level based on a boolean value.

This is what I have so far

## main.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'
import makeRoutes from './routes'
import Root from './containers/Root'
import configureStore from './redux/configureStore'

import * as log from 'loglevel'
if (__DEV__) {
  log.setLevel('DEBUG')
} else { 
  log.setLevel('ERROR')
}
// ...
```

## some other imported file (like middleware/api.js)

```
// ...
log.debug('Fetching data from backend')
```

Comment: Just importing `loglevel` where you need it should work fine I guess. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: tried that, it doesn't really work. if i import in main.js and set the level to ERROR, then later on in another file i import it and query the current level its set to DEBUG

Comment: Then create your own module that wraps `loglevel`, initializes it accordingly and import that instead.

Comment: thanks i did a very basic logger wrapper that just checks and sets the loglevel based on `__DEV__` then exports loglevel as log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the code i ended up going with..

**middleware/logger.js**

```
import * as loglevel from 'loglevel'

if (!__PROD__) {
  loglevel.setLevel('debug')
} else {
  loglevel.setLevel('error')
}

export default loglevel
```

then anywhere i want to use it, i just `import log from 'middleware/logger'`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating a small util that I import and call getLogger() on.

```
export function getLogger() {
    var level = localStorage.getItem('loglevel:cerberus') || 'INFO'
    var log = require("loglevel").getLogger("cerberus")
    log.setLevel(level)
    return log
}
```

Then in a Component where I would like to log

```
import * as logUtils from 'logUtils'
var log = logUtils.getLogger()

...
...
...


log.debug("built the following array of rolePermissionsComponents", rolePermissionsComponents)
```

Then I can use a chrome local storage extension for changing the log level.
My app is 100% client side.

You could easily write your own logic in the util for managing your log level as you see fit.

Comment: thanks, i ended up doign something similar but forgot to answer my own question. I've answered it now with how im doing it.